# XPath query doesn't seem to be working in Google Sheets

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following `id="dataDiv"` tag below

I want to extract it using `IMPORTXML`

```
=IMPORTXML("https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/equities_stock_watch.htm?cat=N","//div/@id=dataDiv")
```

but I get the boolean value `False` and not the table in the div itself. How do I fix this?

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

`//div/@id=dataDiv` is not a valid xpath locator.
Please try: `//div[@id='dataDiv']`

Answer (score 0):

this is not an issue of XPath. the website you are trying to scrape is dependant on JavaScript. Google Sheets does not support import of JS elements. your only option is to find the same data you need on some other website. you can test the JS dependency simply by disabling it for a given site and what's left of it can be scraped - in your case, nothing:

[image: 0]

---

source code scraping:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/equities_stock_watch.htm?cat=N"), 5000, 5)
```